# is there any thing wrong with include , why i cannot find strlen()

Tags: c++

```
#include "Q1-VerifyUniqueCharInString.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


bool isUniqueChar(string str)
{

    int length=strlen(str),i=0;
    bool tab[] = new bool[length];
    if (length > 0xff) {
        return false;
    }
    for (; i<length;++i) {
        if (str[i]) {
            return false;
        }
        tab[str[i]]=true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is my code, and i use gcc+xcode....why there is always tell me cannot find strlen, i use both cstring and string.h...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strlen` applies to a `const char*`, not to a `string`. You can (and should) instead use `str.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

the c string and c++ string lib's are very different from each other, and cannot be mixed. A fix to this would be to treat the string as a c string:

```
strlen(str.c_str()); //convert string into char *
```

c++ string holds and internal c string for easy portability into c code and c methods.

It would also be good to note that `cstring` and `string.h` refer to the same file, c is the c++ method to organize c++ libs and c libs

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib> //could be stdlib.h, but used to show that this lib is a c lib
#include <csting>  //same as string.h
#include <string>  //c++ string lib
```